# How to create context object accessible application-wide to store current user details in data access?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, design-patterns, audit-trail

I have an n-tier web application with a Web UserInterface, BusinessLogicLayer and DataAccessLayer. I am looking for the best possible solution to pass my current logged in user's details all the way to the data-access without add it to all my method signatures. The user details are needed for auditing purposes. I believe you can create a context that is available application wide, is there anyone with an example of doing this? I am looking for the best design pattern that will separate my concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

**First**
This approach makes more sense if those other layers actually need to know about the user. For example, they might check permissions or make some decision based on who the user is.

You can create an abstraction or interface to describe what you want those classes to be able to access, something like this:

```
public interface IUserContext
{
    SomeClassContainingUserData GetCurrentUser();
}
```

I'd define that user data class according to what the consumer class needs instead of just using some existing `Customer` class just to keep this from getting tightly coupled to your web app.

Now you can inject that class into your other classes:

```
public class MyBusinessLogicClass
{
    private readonly IUserContext _userContext;

    public MyBusinessLogicClass(IUserContext userContext)
    {
        _userContext = userContext;
    }

    public void SomeOtherMethod(Whatever whatever)
    {
        var user = _userContext.GetCurrentUser();
        // do whatever you need to with that user
    }
}
```

This keeps your other classes testable because it's easy to inject a mock of the interface that returns what you want so you can make sure your class behaves correctly for different types of users.

If your user data comes from `HttpContext` then your runtime implementation could look roughly like this:

```
public class HttpUserContext
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public HttpUserContext(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public SomeClassContainingUserData GetCurrentUser()
    {
        var httpContext = _contextAccessor.HttpContext;
        // get the user data from the context and return it.
    }
}
```

That's a rough outline. One consideration is scoping. If all of your objects are scoped per-request then the `IUserContext` implementation could generate the user data once and store it in a member variable instead of accessing it over and over.

The drawback is having to inject this everywhere, but that's inevitable if those classes need that information.

**Second**
What if those inner classes don't actually need user information at all? What if you just want to log which users made requests that were handled by those classes? What if you want a separate object to check permissions?

In that case an option would be an interceptor or a wrapper. In its simplest form it could look like this:

```
public class SomeBusinessClassSecurityInterceptor : ISomeBusinessClass
{
    private readonly ISomeBusinessClass _inner;
    private readonly IUserContext _userContext;

    public SomeBusinessClassSecurityInterceptor(
        ISomeBusinessClass inner, IUserContext userContext)
    {
        _inner = inner;
        _userContext = userContext;
    }

    public void UpdateSomeData(Foo data)
    {
        if(!CanUpdate()) 
            throw new YouCantUpdateThisException();
        _inner.UpdateSomeData(data);
    }

    private bool CanUpdate()
    {
        var user = _userContext.GetCurrentUser();
        // make some decision based on the user
    }   
}
```

If retrieving permissions for a user is more involved, you might want to have an `IUserPermissions` and inject that instead of `IUserContext`. Then inject `IUserContext` into the implemenation of `IUserPermissions`. At runtime it retrieves the current user and then does its own thing to determine what permissions the user has.

If you've got lots of classes and methods then maintaining separate wrapper classes could become tedious. Another option is to use an interceptor which likely means using a different dependency injection container like [Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/interceptors.md) or [Autofac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html). These are especially good for logging.

Using Autofac as an example, that would mean writing a class like this:

```
public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly IUserContext _userContext;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public CallLogger(IUserContext userContext, ILogger logger)
    {
        _userContext = userContext;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var user = _userContext.GetCurrentUser();
        _logger.Log( 
         // some stuff about the invocation, like method name and maybe parameters)
         // and who the user was.
         // Or if you were checking permissions you could throw an exception here.

        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

Then you would tell the container that all calls to the "real" implementation of a given class go through this interceptor (described very well in their documentation.)

If you were checking permissions you could inject `IUserPermissions`. The interceptor could check for an attribute on the inner method that specifies what permissions are needed and compare that to the current user's permissions.

You can typically write one interceptor and use it with lots of other classes because it doesn't need to know anything about the inner target class. But if you need to you can also write more narrowly-purposed interceptors used just for certain classes.

What's nice is that it gives you a lot of flexibility but doesn't touch the actual interface or implementation of your business logic or data classes. They can focus on their single responsibilities while other classes are configured to log requests made to them or check user permissions.

Comment: This was a brilliant explanation and a lot of what you have mentioned was my thinking but I was not sure how to layout my thoughts. I  n fact I will need to find a medium between both options as I need to implement both logic that requires to know the user information to perform actions and also I need to log for auditing purposes. Thank you